# Django registration with confirmation email, error: save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'

Tags: django, django-views

I'm trying to create confirm email system, bu I got the same error as in title, anyone know how to solve it?

```
class StudentSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = StudentSignUpForm
    template_name = 'registration/signup_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()
        current_site = get_current_site(self.request)
        mail_subject = 'Activate your account.'
        message = render_to_string('core/acc_active_email.html', {
            'user': user,'domain': current_site.domain,
            'uid': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            'token': account_activation_token.make_token(user),
        })
        to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        email = EmailMessage(
            mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
        )
        email.send()
        return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address to complete the registration')
```

**`forms.py`**

```
class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_student = True
        user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: add your `StudentSignUpForm` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `save` method in the form is not accepting *any* argument, and you are passing `commit=False` to it; You should add the argument to the `save` method:

```
def save(self, commit=True, *args, **kwargs):
        user = super().save(commit=False, *args, **kwargs)
        user.is_student = True
        user.save()
        return user
```

Generally, when you override a built-in method, you should keep the method signature *as it was originally declared*.